# How to alter a queue table's column from byte semantics to character semantics (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

How can I alter a queue table's column from byte semantics to character semantics? (oracle 10/11g)

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm) correctly, ALTER TABLE should work as expected - the only restriction mentioned there is that you cannot add a new column to a queue table.

Comment: Sorry man, ALTER TABLE will not work. It will return ORA-24005. I did google it, and the results are not helpful. Hope someone can point out. See: http://www.error-code.org.uk/view.asp?e=ORACLE-ORA-24005